# Height of trapezoid knowing the area

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Dear stackexchange community,

I run into this issue:

I need to find the height of a rectangle trapezium knowing:

- Greater base $B$
- Height if it would be vertically extended to become a rectangle triangle $h_{max}$

What I need to find is a formula $h = f(A)$ which, given the trapezium area, it returns the trapezium height.

I tried in the following ways:

**Method $1$**

Considering:

- the area (which we know) is a function of height and the two basis (which we know the greater one)
- we can calculate the minor basis

We can reverse the formula:

$$
\begin{align}
b & = B (1 - \frac{h}{h_{max}}) \\
A & = \frac{(B + b) h}{2} \\
h & = \frac{2 A}{(B + b)} \\
h & = \frac{2 A}{B + B  (1 - \frac{h}{h_{max}})} \\
h & = \frac{2 A}{2B - B\frac{h}{h_{max}}} \\
\frac{h}{h} & = \frac{2 A}{(2B - B\frac{h}{h_{max}})}\frac{1}{h} \\
1 & = \frac{2 A}{h(2B - B\frac{h}{h_{max}})}\\ 
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
h(2B - B\frac{h}{h_{max}}) & = 2 A\\ 
2Bh - Bh\frac{h}{h_{max}} & = 2 A\\ 
2B h - \frac{B}{h_{max}} h^2 - 2A & = 0 \\
- \frac{B}{h_{max}} h^2 + 2B  h- 2A & = 0 \\
- \frac{B}{h_{max}} h^2 + 2B  h- 2A & = 0
\end{align}
$$

which is a second order equations with these terms:

$$
\begin{align}
y & = a x^2 + b x + c \\
a & = - \frac{B}{h_{max}} \\
b & = 2B \\
c & = - 2A
\end{align}
$$

**Method $2$**

We can consider the greater base and the height of the trapezoid as the X-Y axis of a cartesian plane. In this way we can consider the oblique side as a straight line and the trapezoid area like the area below this straight line.

Using the integral we can get the formula of the area and reverse it to get the height:

$$
\begin{align}
y & = mx + q \\
y & = \int(mx + q) dx \\
y & = \frac{1}{2}mx^2 + qx \\
\end{align}
$$

the integral computed between $0$ and $h$ : $ y = \int_{0}^{h}(mx + q) dx $

where $m$ is the inclination of the oblique side and $q$ is the $B$, the integral computed between $0$ and $h$

So it become:

$$
\begin{align}
A & = (\frac{1}{2}mx^2 + qx)|_h - (\frac{1}{2}mx^2 + qx)|_0  \\ 
 & = (\frac{1}{2}mh^2 + Bh) \\ 
\end{align} \\
(\frac{1}{2}mh^2 + Bh) - A = 0 \\
m = \frac{h_{max}}{B} \\
\frac{h_{max}}{2B}h^2 + Bh - A = 0 \\
$$

which is a second order equations with these terms:

$$
\begin{align}
y & = a x^2 + b x + c \\
a & = \frac{h_{max}}{2B} \\
b & = B \\
c & = -A
\end{align}
$$

**Conclusion**
As you can see the two formula are different (or their coefficients at least) which lead me to thing I made something obviously wrong.

On top of that, testing them with some test case gives me very wrong number.

Do you have any clue on what I am doing wrong? Just some bad math or the concept (either the first or the second method) is totally wrong?

Thank you

Comment: It would really help the community if you attach a diagram showing the setup of the problem.

Comment: I tried to attach a couple of pictures, but I am a new user and I still cannot post images. If by "diagram" you meant something else, can you tell me more, please?

Comment: No, I didn't mean anything else, by 'diagram' I mean an image or figure that has the layout of your trapezoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of roots, they are the same equation.
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ is equivalent to $$\frac12ax^2+\frac12bx+\frac12c=0$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see the reason on that (dividing both member by 2 doesn't change the result), but it seems to me that the two results, aside the division by two, are similar but not equal.

In fact, one is (divided by 2):
$$
\begin{align}
a & = -\frac{B}{2h_{max}} \\
b & = B \\
c & = -A
\end{align}
$$
where the other are:
$$
\begin{align}
a & = \frac{h_{max}}{2B} \\
b & = B \\
c & = -A
\end{align}
$$
Did I miss something?

Comment: You are getting confused in the notations. I think that in your second method your $x$ is along the height, and $y$ is along the long base, at $x=0$. Then the slope is $-\frac{B}{h_{max}}$

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake.
Sorry for late reply, I had an other error which prevented me to properly use the formula which I just found and solved it.

Thank you very much